# Tangram [error]: Scene.load() failed to load blob in heremap (mapsjs-core.js:435:68531)

Tags: blob, heremaps, here-maps-rest, tangram

In Few Domains,
hereMap not loading
getting below error in console

Tangram [error]: Scene.load() failed to load blob:https://www.amazon.com/e1e49547-17c5-4c99-ab8a-f359e12ad21a: Worker broker could not add non-Worker object Error: Worker broker could not add non-Worker object
at WorkerBroker.addWorker (mapsjs-core.js:435:68531)
mapsjs-core.js:435

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Worker broker could not add non-Worker object
at WorkerBroker.addWorker (mapsjs-core.js:435:68531)
at mapsjs-core.js:435:604245

It is fine in another pages, it is failing in specific pages

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please make sure Another external script of Worker broker constructor shouldn't override your actual Work-Broker and that shouldn't create a non-Worker object

Comment: Removed Unwanted Script which created Worker broker constructor & looks good now